# Javascript Error: Expected an identifier and instead saw '}'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using http://www.jslint.com/ to validate a small script and it's giving me this error

```
Expected an identifier and instead saw '}'
On line 13: })
```

I need help to understand what is wrong with the script and how to stop the error. Also since i built this script with tips found online please let me know if it has other errors no mentioned by the debugger.
Full code:

```
(function($) {
  $(".acf-get-content-button").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".fa").addClass("fa-cog fa-spin fa-4x");
var $contentWrapper = $("#acf-content-wrapper");
var postId = $contentWrapper.data("id");

    $.ajax({
        url: "/ajax.php",
        "type": "POST",
        "data": {
          "post_id": postId
        },
      })
      .done(function(data) {
        $(".fa").removeClass("fa-cog fa-spin fa-4x");
        $contentWrapper.append(data);
        $("#acf-content-wrapper a").attr("target","_blank");
        $("#acf-content-wrapper").bind("contextmenu", function(e) {
        return false;
        });
        $(".acf-get-content-button").removeClass().addClass(".acf-get-content-button")
      });
  });
  $(".acf-get-content-button").mouseup(function() {
    if (event.which == 1) {
      $(".acf-get-content-button").hide();
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Remove the comma in line 12

Comment: Please find some proper IDE

Comment: Recommend me a proper IDE please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that the jslint error is the last comma in

```
"data": {
    "post_id": postId
},
```

It should be

```
"data": {
    "post_id": postId
}
```

Comment: Wow so silly, now it tells me
`Unused 'e'.
$("#acf-content-wrapper").bind("contextmenu", function(e) {`
What could that be? Change e with data? Does that make sense?

Comment: remove `e`, you are not using it inside the function `$("#acf-content-wrapper").bind("contextmenu", function() {`